# Change order of executing CDI Interceprors and ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, deltaspike

I am using Deltaspike **SecurityInterceptor** to authorize methods with **@LoggedIn** annotation.

At the same time I am authenticating user with token at **ContainerRequestFilter**.

```
@Inject
AuthenticationService authenticationService;

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    String authToken = requestContext.getHeaderString(AUTH_TOKEN);

    try {
        authenticationService.authenticateWithToken(authToken);
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        log.info(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have faced the problem that container firstly executes **SecurityInterceptor** and then **ContainerRequestFilter** and user gets not authenticated.

Is there any way to change the execution order?

**My beans.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
<interceptors>
    <class>org.apache.deltaspike.security.impl.extension.SecurityInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From javaee7 documentation:

> [If an application uses more than one interceptor, the interceptors are invoked in the order specified in the beans.xml file.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv006.htm#GKHJX)

But interceptors and filters doesn't has any execution correlation, filters act on web request, interceptors are CDI objects, i think that any runtime execution dependency is a design error.

Where is the interceptor annotation? Which class?

Comment: I have moved back from mixing interceptors and request filters. These are different tiers of application. When I dealing with requests I use request filters and interrupt each unauthenticated request before it proceed. When I work with beans I use deltaspike security.